# Cannot receive large amount of serial data from Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing

I am trying to receive sensor data from Arduino and write the readings into a file using Processing IDE (using serial communication / USB).

After doing a large amount of tests, I am pretty sure it's the Processing side unable to process the data. **Only the first few (< 100) "samples" are written successfully, after that `Serial.available()` always returns false.**

I am sending two-byte chunks from Arduino, 57600 baud, default settings (8 bit, no parity, 1 stop bit).

Arduino code:

```cpp
unsigned int data = 0;
unsigned char buf[2];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {

  data = analogRead(A0);

  buf[0] = data & 0xFF; // low byte
  buf[1] = data >> 8;   // high byte

  Serial.write(buf, 2);
  Serial.flush();

  delayMicroseconds(300);
}
```

Processing code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial serialPort;
String serialData;
PrintWriter output;

int recordingTime = 1000;          // how many miliseconds of data stream to record
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[2];   // reserve memory for 2 bytes and initialize to 0 (java stuff)
int receivedBytes = 0;

void setup()
{
  serialPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600);
  output = createWriter("serialData.txt");
}

void draw()
{

  while(millis() < recordingTime) {

    if (serialPort.available() > 0) {
      receivedBytes = serialPort.readBytes(dataBuffer);

      output.print("\n");
      output.print("Received bytes: ");
      output.print(receivedBytes);
      output.print("\n");

      output.println(binary(dataBuffer[0]));  // low byte
      output.println(binary(dataBuffer[1]));  // high byte
      output.println("");
    }    
    else {
      output.print("\n");
      output.println("No data available");
    }

  }

  output.flush();
  output.close();
  exit();  
}
```

Output:

```
Received bytes: 2
11101001
00000011


Received bytes: 2
11101001
00000011


Received bytes: 2
11101001
00000011

...after some lines...

No data available

No data available

No data available

No data available

No data available

No data available
```

**Why is this happening?** Why is there "no data available" after few samples? If I watch the serial monitor output in Arduino IDE, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can read the serial data from Arduino using `screen` and using Python. Still cannot get it to work in Processing - only receiving few samples (17 exactly).

Screen command: `$ screen <port name> <baud rate>` (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to stop the program; add -L flag for logging to a file). Works as expected.

I managed to achieve the same results using [Pyserial library](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html) in Python:

```
#
#   log_serial.py
#   Writes incoming serial data to file.

import time
import serial

# Edit this parameters =========================================================

serialPort = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
baudrate = 57600
recordTime = 1000   # milliseconds

# ==============================================================================


def millis():
    """
    Returns current (wall-)time in milliseconds
    """
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))


ser = serial.Serial(serialPort, baudrate)

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:

    startTime = millis()

    f.write("Recording started at: ")
    f.write(str(startTime))
    f.write("\n")

    while (millis() - startTime) <= recordTime:
        inData = ser.read(2)                                        # reads two bytes
        inInt = int.from_bytes(inData, byteorder='little')          # merges them into an integer

        f.write(str(inInt))
        f.write("\n")

    f.write("Recording finished at: ")
    f.write(str(millis()))
    f.write("\n")
```

Still don't know why the Processing version can't handle it...
There was a bug (wrong while loop condition) in my first Processing code. Here is updated version, using `Serial.read()` rather than `Serial.readBytes(buffer)`. Still doesn't solve my problem, only getting 17 samples:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial serialPort;
String serialData;
PrintWriter output;

int recordingTime = 5000;          // how many miliseconds of data stream to record

void setup()
{
  serialPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600);
  output = createWriter("serialData.txt");
}

void draw()
{

  int startTime = millis();
  while((millis() - startTime) <= recordingTime) {

    if (serialPort.available() > 0) {

      int b1 = serialPort.read();
      int b2 = serialPort.read();

      int value = (b2 << 8) + (b1 & 0xFF);
      output.println(value);
    }

  }

  output.flush();
  output.close();
  exit();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to run this code and post the content of the written file afterwards:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial serialPort;
String serialData;
PrintWriter output;

int recordingTime = 5000;          // how many miliseconds of data stream to record

void setup()
{
  serialPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600);
  output = createWriter("serialData.txt");
}

void draw()
{

  int startTime = millis();
  while((millis() - startTime) <= recordingTime) {

    if (serialPort.available() > 0) {

      int b1 = serialPort.read();
      int b2 = serialPort.read();

      int value = (b2 << 8) + (b1 & 0xFF);
      output.print(millis());    //to each received value there is written the actual millis()-value
      output.print(",");
      output.println(value);
    }

  }

  output.flush();
  output.close();
  exit();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems with the Serial communication between Processing and my Arduino Uno/Mega using `serialPort.read()` instead of `serialPort.readBytes(dataBuffer)`. Maybe this makes a difference...

Have you already tried to increase the variable `recordingTime`?

Comment: I tried using the read() function, readBytes(), serialEvent(), all of them...always the same, not getting more than few samples.

There is a bug in the Processing while condition. Should define `int startTime` first, and then the condition should look like: `while((millis() - startTime) <= recordingTime)` ...
But this is not the problem apparently. It's strange because the "same" code in python works well...

Comment: But in the Processing-Code you didn't use a variable called startTime...

Comment: Exactly, I noticed that mistake after posting, but it doesn't solve my problem anyway...

Comment: I edited my previous answer, added updated version of Processing code

Comment: Try to use only the following line of code in your Processing loop: 'output.println(serialPort.read())'. If there isn't the problem with the limited amount of received data with this line of code, you have to proof the while and the if condition. Otherwise there is a general problem with the serial communication. Another problem could be your output, so also try out the Processing console instead of your written file...